# How to open context menu after onLongClick event on a CardView List android?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview, onlongclicklistener

I have shown a list of contacts in `CardView` on `RecyclerView` and now i want to open a context menu when i call `OnLongClick` event on particular `CardView`.

Like edit, delete options.

In `CardView` layout i have added two layout, left side contact are showing and right side two buttons added history and status where different event handlers handle.

If I press long click on `CardView` a popup window open where i can edit and delete contact and from those options like - delete or edit click event will handle for particular contact.

`ContactAdapter` code:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder>  {
ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Context ctx;

public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> contacts,Context ctx) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);
    ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view,ctx,contacts);
    return contactViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact CON = contacts.get(position);
    holder.person_name.setText(CON.getName());
    holder.person_email.setText(CON.getEmail());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
    TextView person_name, person_email,btn_history,btn_task_update;
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Context ctx;
    CardView card_view;

    public ContactViewHolder(View view, Context ctx ,ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        super(view);
        this.contacts=contacts;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        person_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        person_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_email);
        card_view =  (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        btn_history = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_history);
        btn_task_update= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_task_update);
        card_view.setOnClickListener(this);
        card_view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        btn_history.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_task_update.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Contact contact = this.contacts.get(position);
        if(v.getId()==R.id.card_view) {
            Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "position Card View" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_history)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "position History" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_task_update)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "position Task Status" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, task_detail.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", contact.getName());
            intent.putExtra("email", contact.getEmail());
            this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Contact contact = this.contacts.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if( v.getId() == R.id.card_view ) {
               int position = getAdapterPosition();
               Contact contact = this.contacts.get(position);
               showDialog( contact, new CustomActionListener() {
                   void onAction( int actionType ) {
                     switch( actionType ) {
                        case OPTION_EDIT :
                         //edit contact here
                         break;
                        case OPTION_DELETE :
                         //delete contact here
                         break;
                        default :
                        //On dialog dismiss - do nothing
                        break;
                     }
                   }
               } ); 
               /* show your popup dialog here, it would be good 
                if you have an interface defined for the kind of action that was performed in dialog, using that, 
                perform required action here. */ 
            }

        return true;
    }

       // Your custom interface
       public interface CustomActionListener {
            void onAction( int actionType );
       }
```

Define a showDialog function with popup window with buttons to complete the above pseudo code.